# Android application with AngularJS in webview

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

How can I use AngularJS & H5 for building an Android native/hybrid app without using PhoneGap or Cordova, just simple webview inside android layout file.

Please provide some reference :)

Answer (score 2):

Any AngularJS web app runs fine in a `WebView`.

To run the website in a `WebView` all you need to do is this.

```
final WebView containerWbVw = findViewById(R.id.fragment_wbVw_container_id);
WebSettings webSettings = containerWbVw.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
containerWbVw.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

and then load the URL in the `WebView` using

```
containerWbVw.loadUrl(WEBAPP_URL);
```

The `WEBAPP_URL` can be an HTML page in your assets folder or hosted on your server

```
//assets folder file
WEBAPP_URL = "file:///android_asset/main.html";
//server link
WEBAPP_URL="https://mysite.mycompany.com/myapp";
```

In addition to this, you would need to interact with the native android app to send and receive data. For example, a use case would be to get a scanned barcode using the device's camera. For this, you would need a [Javasrcript Bridge](https://github.com/gzsll/WebViewJavascriptBridge).

Comment: So i need to create html file and put into asset folder & call load url? but how my angular code will run